# Can't change miller rabin formula to calculate error?

Tags: python, algorithm, refactoring, syntax-error, probability

How would I determine the numbers that aren't prime, and that my equation says it is prime?

Lets say 100-1000 numbers that are prime, and by definition from wikipedia, "which detect all composites (once again, this means: for every composite number n, at least 3/4 (Miller–Rabin) or 1/2 (Solovay–Strassen) of numbers a are witnesses of compositeness of n). "

How would I change the formula for error estimate?

```
from random import randrange

def miller-rabin(i, k):
    """
    Miller Rabin written in Python
    :param i: i is the number to check for primality
    :param k: is the security value
    :return: True is the number is prime, false if not
    """
    #base case 1
    if i < 2 or i % 2 == 0:
        return False

    #case 2
    if i == 2:
        return True

    r = 0
    s = i - 1
    #create initial equation n-1 = 2^(u*r)
    while s % 2 == 0:
        r += 1
        s //= 2
    for _ in range(k):
        a = randrange(2, i-1)
        x = pow(a, s, i)
        if x == 1 or x == i - 1:
            continue
        for _ in range( r - 1):
            x = pow(x, 2, i)
            if x == i - 1:
                break
        else:
            return False
    return True

print(millerR(10, 5))
```

Comment: How do you define `error estimate`?